# Installing Quicken 2016 on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, installation, quicken

I've just bought a new PC that runs Windows 10 and I'm trying to install Quicken 2016 on it.  The PC that I'm replacing was also running Windows 10 and ran Quicken 2016 just fine - that installation was done in Win 7, however.

I have another PC that I bought in 2017 in which I had successfully isntalled and currently run Quicken 2016 on Win 10.

I'm using the original install file I got from eCrater when I bought the software in 2016.

When I run the installer, it successfully unpacks the install files into a temp folder in AppData\Local\Temp. But it's trying to run Setup.exe and it just ... does nothing. Windows asks me if I want to allow Quicken to modify my computer and I say yes. The task manager gets a new line called "Quicken Installer (32 bit)" and it stays in memory and uses a small % of CPU (5-7% typically), but there's no GUI, my computer doesn't freeze or lock up - it just does nothing.

What I've tried:

- Leaving it overnight (no change)
- Running Setup.exe directly from the Temp folder instead of using the downloaded installer
- Changing compatibility to run on Win 7, Win 8, Win Vista sp1, Win Vista sp2 (no difference)
- Changing compatibility to run on Win XP (pops up an error message saying my computer is not capable of running Quicken)
- Having Setup.exe run in Administrator mode
- Changing compatibility to run in 640x480
- Tuning off the Windows firewall
- Uninstalling McAfee
- Turning off Windows virus tamper protection
- Copying the Program Files/Quicken files to the new PC and running that (no error - just nothing happens)

What have I missed? I *know* this works on Win 10 from experience. What else can I try to get the installer working? Is there something I can do manually?

Comment: You are running the most recent installer of Quicken 2016, having installed it myself, I know it received numerous updates while it was supported.

Comment: Is this computer in a domain?

Comment: I searched and Quicken 2016 officially supports Windows 10, so that isn't a concern.

Comment: Ramhound, I have more recent patch executables, but the only installer is the original from 2015. When I try to run a patch executable it tells me I don't have quicken installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well known problem but solution is buried...this is the post you want to read, with the links/info you need:

https://community.quicken.com/discussion/7857611/quicken-2016-offline-use-only

MOST important....shut off your internet connection when doing the install and applying the patches. Also, once installed, ensure that you block all the EXEs in the Quicken folder...do NOT run 2016 with an internet connection because then you will have to re-install because they update the EXEs without consent.

And this might short cut your process:

You need to download the following patches:  8, 12, 14.1 and finally 19.5 from:
http://www.quicknperlwiz.com/quickenpatches.html

All patches must be applied, before you launch or open Quicken.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you so much and thanks for joining SE to answer this question!